# Java JPanel and JFrame border dragging

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am opening a window with the following:

```
JFrame clientFrame = new JFrame("Frame");
clientFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
final JPanel client_panel = new JPanel();
client_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
client_panel.add(new Applet());
client_panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(765, 555));
clientFrame.getContentPane().add(client_panel, "Center");
clientFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
clientFrame.pack();
clientFrame.setVisible(true);
```

the frame has a random picture on it.

By default when you drag the bottom border upwards, it will naturally remove from the image from the bottom of the image.

The same if you drag the top border downwards it will again remove incrementally from the bottom of the picture.

How do I swap it around so instead it removes form the top of the picture instead of from the bottom?

Comment: This will depend on the code which allows the display of the image to your window.  Please edit your question and add that code.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clientFrame.getContentPane().add(client_panel, "Center");
```

Don't use magic values. People don't know where "Center" comes form. Use variables provided by the API:

```
clientFrame.getContentPane().add(client_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

What you are asking is not possible with any layout manager that I am aware of. The problem is that the layout manager only knows about size available to the component. It does not know why the size changed (ie, drag up or down). So the layout manager can only define rules based on the space available.

As a simple test use a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout`. Then create a `JLabel` with containing an `ImageIcon`. Add the label to this panel and then add the panel to the content pane of the frame.

If you add the label to the BorderLayout.CENTER, then the image is centered in the space available so you lose part of the top and bottom.

If you add the label to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START then space is always taken from (or given to) the bottom of the component.

If you add the label to the BorderLayout.PAGE_END then space is always taken from (or given to) the top of the component.

If you want to consider the drag up or down of the frame then the solution gets much more complicated because you will need to add a `ComponentListener` to the frame and handle the `componentResized` and `componentMoved` methods. You will then need to track the previous state of the frame and then determine which properties have changed and then you will need to do custom painting of the image based on the property changes or you will need to write a custom layout manager that is aware of the property changes.